# How do I internally link to another HTMLtemplating engine page using Express.js?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express

I have two Pug (templating engine) files in a /views folder: index.pug and search.pug. I have the following line of code in index.pug:

```
    a(href="/search.pug") Search
```

I have these lines of code in my js file:

```
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static('views'));
```

Now, if I click on the link to the search.pug page on the index.pug page, it downloads the search.pug page instead of linking to it. How do I fix this?

I've changed it to app.use(express.static('/views')); now instead of downloading the page, I get redirected to a page saying: Cannot GET /search.pug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this like this.
You need to handle the request in you express like this:

```
a(href='//yourDomain/search')

app.get("/search", (req, res) => {
    res.render("search.pug");
};
```

Comment: Glad it helped you, have a happy code day :) @PrecentJohn